# Using apex:relatedList in a Visualforce page when the user profile denies access to child objects

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, force.com

I have two custom objects, Appointment and Session Report.  Session Report is a child of Appointment in a standard Master-Detail relationship.  Additionally, I have a profile, Student, which has Read-Create-Edit-Delete for Appointments and no rights for Session Reports.  The use case is a Student can create an Appointment but cannot view the Session Reports created for this Appointment by a Tutor.

Using a standard layout for the Appointment object works as expected when viewing Appointments.  Namely, the Student can see the Appointment fields and the related list of Session Reports is not displayed.  All other user profiles observe can see the related list of Session Reports.

However, I have encountered a problem when replacing the standard layout with a Visualforce page as such:

```
<apex:page standardController="Appointment__c">
<apex:sectionHeader title="{!$ObjectType.Appointment__c.label}" subtitle="{!Appointment__c.Name}"/>
<apex:pageBlock title="{!$ObjectType.Appointment__c.label} Detail">
    <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="1">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Appointment__c.Tutor_Name__c}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Appointment__c.Student_Name__c}"/>           
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock>    
 <apex:relatedList list="Session_Reports__r"/>
```

This new page works as expected for all users with at least Read rights for the Session Report object.  The Student user has no rights to this object and receives this error message

```
'Session_Reports__r' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Appointment
```

Clearly this relationship does exist as the page can be displayed properly for users with different profiles.  I have been unable to resolve the difference between the standard layout and the VF page that would result in this failure.  It has been suggested to me that I could identify the user profile in the VF page and use that information to toggle rendering.  However, this type of approach defeats the purpose of the Salesforce security model and I won't be adopting such a technique.

Should I be able to use apex:relatedList in this fashion?  Or have I wrongly assumed that the VF rendering engine could figure out when it can and cannot display related lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce security model is only going to ensure you don't show data that is not accessible to a particular user.  How it does this is by throwing that exception you see.  If you're building a custom vf page your responsible for making sure you don't display something the user isn't allowed to see.  Note this is different than for fields which just don't show up if the user doesn't have the proper field level security.

You'll need to add a check to verify a user can view that object.  Fortunately they have a lot of "is" methods (isAccessible, isCreatable, isDeletable, etc.) on the [Describe Object Result](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) for you to determine what the current user's permissions are for that object without having to hard code profiles into your code.  For your specific case you don't what to display that related list if it's object not accessible.

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:relatedList list="Session_Reports__r" 
                  rendered="{!$ObjectType.Session_Report__c.accessible}"/>
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I wasn't looking for - you are correct and I continue to find much displeasure working in this evironment.  I did use a different approach `<apex:relatedList list="Grades__r" rendered="{!$ObjectType.Grade__c.accessible}"/>` which worked, too.

Comment: I have been stewing over why this solution is so unpalatable when the answer was right in my Visualforce page.  Namely, when I use this tag `<apex:outputField value="{!Tutor__c.Notes__c}"/>` and the Notes__c field is not visible to the user profile... it just doesn't show up on  the page.  And I don't have to do anything to make this happen.  No test for isAccessible, nothing.  That's probably why I was biased towards the original markup.

Comment: Nice catch that you could access isAccessible by just dropping the is.  Updated the answer.  I feel you on the fact this should be handled automatically, but it's best to get over that expectation with salesforce early.  If they don't get it right on the first try they're not going to come back and clean up a feature to make it easier.  Even if it's flat out broken there isn't a guarantee it'll get attention from QA